# Multi-tenant architecture

Tags: php, multi-tenant

I've made an app that had every client on their own database.

It's now grown to the point that I'm thinking a better way for future updates of schema, would be the one-table multi-tenant type solution.

What are the downsides to this?

The one-table will basically be a table of leads,
shared by multiple companies.
At the current size, that's about 15,000,000 rows so far.
What are the implications of this table becoming too large, and how would I deal with it?

Salesforce has a one-table Oracle database.
Which must be massive!!
I'm just wondering how they deal with a constantly updating dataset, in terms of caches and locking, etc.

Comment: You are trading maintainability for speed right now.  If you switch you will trade speed for maintainability.  Since this is sales, you need to consider your client's wishes with regards to data security.  They may not want to be on a shared database, especially if it means a couple small coding mistakes mean their competitors on your system can see all their records.

Comment: Are you using any particular framework for your app? Laravel has database `migration` functionality which allows you to update your database schema and roll it back programmatically, from the command line. You can also use tools like Chef or Puppet to help you automate your databases via scripting, which can be version controlled.

Comment: Im using Laravel.  But haven't even used any of the migration features.  Since I basically plugged this ontop of an already existing system.  But I guess Ill look into it now..

Comment: I'm just learning them myself. Do you simply have one installation of your client app (ie, one production server/cluster)?

Comment: No its multiple copies.  On multiple servers/databases.  I want to make it one copy.  With a shared database for users, sales etc.  But seperate client databases for each clients customers/appointments...or just seperate client_tables within the main database

Comment: Then definitely look into migrations. This way whenever you update a given client's installation, you're just running the version-controlled migration files which you can unit test on a local development server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any particular framework for your app? Laravel has database `migration` (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) functionality which allows you to update your database schema and roll it back programmatically, from the command line. You can also use tools like `Chef` or `Puppet` to help you automate your databases via scripting, which can be version controlled.

This way whenever you update a given client's installation, you're just running the version-controlled migration files which you can unit test on a local development server.